# Cannot expand a table using console.table(). It shows only the first 3 lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

How do I expand the table? It only shows the first 3 lines. I'm using Google Chrome Version 103.0.5060.53 (Official Build) (64-bit) (MX Linux).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFkQj.png)

Comment: And by the way I can't even scroll though the table. It hides the rest of it. I tried almost everything :(

Comment: Only arrays (and arrays of objects) are supported, see [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/api/#table).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about chrome docs

Answer (score 0):

The keys in your object are not unique, hence, it is only showing the last value for the unique keys. Since there are only three unique keys, there is nothing to scroll.

`console.table` is showing exactly what the object contains.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How do I expand the table? It only shows the first ... if you have created a console table of length n then that only shows n-1 rows for any n value.[browser image showing n-1 records when n records are given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VaYc.png) just in case you can't expand initially like as below =>
[before expand pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAkh0.png) then double click on any header fields of the table to expand which is as below =>[[after expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBEAO.png) ], then you would be able to see the table contents :)This is been tested on Version 103.0.5060.134 (Official Build) (64-bit) Chrome. also seem to work the same for MicrosoftEdge! Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).